# Name the resources with the supplied parameters to cloud formation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

Im new to cloudformation and intrinsc function.
I am trying to run a stack with the template which accepts ent type as parameter
Using this parameter I would like to name my s3 bucket.

But Im getting 400 Bad request

My template
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Creates an S3 bucket using parameters supplied.",
    "Parameters": {

```
    "AssetInsightId": {
        "Description": "Asset Insight ID",
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "###"
    },
    "ResourceOwner": {
        "Description": "tr:resource-owner",
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "###"
    },
    "EnvironmentType": {
        "Description": "tr:environment-type",

         "Default": "PREPROD",
        "Type": "String",
        "AllowedValues": ["PREPROD", "PROD"],
        "ConstraintDescription": "must specify PREPROD, PROD."
    }
},
"Resources": {
    "ResourceBucket": {
        "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
        "Properties": {
            "BucketName": "!Sub a${AssetInsightId}-S3Bucket-${EnvironmentType}",
            "VersioningConfiguration": {
                "Status": "Enabled"
            },
            "Tags": [

                {
                    "Key": "tr:application-asset-insight-id",
                    "Value": "${AssetInsightId}"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "tr:resource-owner",
                    "Value": "${ResourceOwner}"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "tr:environment-type",
                    "Value": "${EnvironmentType}"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
"Outputs": {
    "BucketName": {
        "Description": "Name of the S3 Resource Bucket",
        "Value": "!Ref ResourceBucket"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Using the AWS CLI - for passing dynamic parameters

```
aws cloudformation create-stack  --stack-name my-stack
--template-body template.json 
--parameters  ParameterKey=EnvironmentType,ParameterValue=Development
```

[From here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/passing-parameters-to-cloudformation-stacks-with-the-aws-cli-and-powershell/)

Also  `!Sub` is the syntax for the short form of `Fn::Sub:` - used in template YAML

`{ "Fn::Sub" : String }` - used in template JSON

[Fn::Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html)

Change

```
"BucketName": "!Sub a${AssetInsightId}-S3Bucket-${EnvironmentType}",
```

To

```
"BucketName": { "Fn::Sub": "a${AssetInsightId}-S3Bucket-${EnvironmentType}"},
```

[Example](https://aws-quickstart.github.io/design-parms.html)

Comment: @Swathi If my answer solved your issue, feel free to up-vote and/or accept the answer. thanks